# How can I take a input from user and change it with setState?

Tags: reactjs

```js
constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = {
    name: "",
    name1: "",
  };
}

change = () => {
  this.setState({ name: this.state.name1 });
};

handleChange = (e) => {
  this.setState({ name1: e.target.value });
};

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Enter your name"
        onChange={this.handleChange}
      ></input>
      <button onClick={this.change}>Click Me!</button>
      <h4>Hello! {this.state.name}</h4>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This is what I did but feels like it is nonsense on actual webpage even it works. Is there a better way to take input from user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why you need name and name1 in state. Just name should be fine. See the below code if that helps

I am not sure why you handle a event in button. May you can use a form with OnSubmit.

```
import React from "react";
import "./style.css";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: "",
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Enter your name"
          onChange={(e) => this.setState({name: e.target.value})}
        />
        <button>Click Me!</button>
        <h4>Hello! {this.state.name}</h4>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to change it while typing an input but onSubmit can really help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your onChange in the input would be

```
onChange={event => this.handleChange(event)}
```

And for the button it would be

```
onChange{() => this.change()}
```

Answer (score 1):

We would not require 2 states for the name but we would need one variable to store the name and second variable to let the component know that name has been update. We need the second variable because on button click only the name has to be updated(as per the code mentioned).The component would re-render when a state is updated. Below code might be helpful.

```
class Content extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super()
    this.state = {
        name: "",
    }
    this.name=''
}

change = () => {
    this.setState({name: this.name})
}

handleChange = (e) => {
    this.name=e.target.value
}

render(){

    return(
        <div>
            <input type = "text" placeholder="Enter your name" onChange={this.handleChange}></input>
            <button onClick={this.change}>Click Me!</button>
            <h4>Hello! {this.state.name}</h4>
        </div>
    )
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version with React Hooks:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export default function App() {
  const [name, setName] = useState('');

  const handleNameChange = (e) => {
    const nameInput = e.target.value;
    setName(nameInput);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Enter your name"
        onChange={(e) => handleNameChange(e)}
      ></input>
      <button>Click Me!</button>
      <h4>Hello! {name}</h4>
    </div>
  );
}
```